# Wrong OS version in Windows CE binary (with Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-ce

I'm trying to create an executable for a Windows CE 5.0 device.

The SDK has been selected right (STANDARDSDK_500 (SH4)) and connection to the device works. However, the binary created by Visual Studio refuses to be "deployed" on the device, claiming that the Windows version is not high enough.

Having a look at the EXE file (with the amazing Dependency Walker utility that supports WinCE binaries) shows "OS Ver" 6.0 and "Subversion" 6.0. I want them to be 5.0!

WHERE does one set this, or WHERE can something be overriding the SDK selection I've made? This is rather frustrating. I'd *like* to like Visual Studio 2010, but it simply makes too much pain, too often. Things should just *work*.

Comment: Don't act on this yet - I'm able to solve it...

Answer (score 2):

Grep on the files revealed that the .vcproj file had lines with

```
AdditionalOptions=" /subsystem:windowsce,6.00"
```

Removing such corrected the problem.

What's sad is that the setting was completely missing on the IDE side, so there's no way to fix it there. It wasn't even shown on the "command line" summaries of what the IDE presumably sends to the actual compiler.

This is why IDE's often suck.